# InputStream Out Of memory

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, inputstream

I'm trying to download an epub from a WebService when low EPUBs small files works .. but when i try with larger EPUBs as 18mb does not work

```
WebServiceCliente webService = new WebServiceCliente();
epubDownloaded = webService.downloadEpub(book);
//Here is the Problem
InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(epubDownloaded);

Book bookEPUB = input;
    try {
         bookEPUB = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

I get the Out Of Memory error with this input

Comment: You need to read the data as it downloads as you don't have enough heap to read all the data into memory first.

Comment: why don't you read some part of it , then saving it to bookEPUB, and then the other part and save again, I think your way, readEpub(input) method takes too much memory from your app memory.